# Searching over Oracle partitions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

Is there a big performance hit when running SQL on a partitioned Oracle table where the SQL does not reference the column that is used for partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your WHERE clause is not based on any index column your query will be very slow, because Oracle has to do a Full-Table-Scan.

If you have a globally defined index on columns in WHERE clause, it does not matter whether you access only one partition or all.

But you get a degradation when your table has many partions and locally defined index which are used by WHERE clause. Assume your table has 50 partitions, and locally defined index, then a query which does not specify the partition (either by WHERE condition or explicitly by partition name) has to scan 50 individual indexes likewise.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on global V locally defined indices?

Comment: What do you mean by "global V"?